# Connection to 127.0.0.1:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections

Tags: java, postgresql, docker, ubuntu

I'm running my code from docker-compose which is trying to access a local database(postgres).
whenever i try to run i get this error

```
Connection to 127.0.0.1:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
```

but postgres is running on port `5432`

here is ther result of `sudo netstat -ltnp | grep postgres`

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5432          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1995/postgres
```

I'am using postgres v 10.9 on ubunto OS.

Comment: If you try to access to localhost inside a container then it's the localhost of the container not your machine or any other container. If both your app and database are declare in the same compose, use the same network you can use the container name.

Comment: Please provide your docker compose file here

Answer (score 0):

> If you try to access to localhost inside a container then it's the localhost of the container not your machine or any other container. If both your app and database are declare in the same compose, use the same network you can use the container name

That is correct, but if you have Postgres installed in you local machine, you could bypass the container restriction setting your machine's IP, e.g. connecting to Postgres to :5432

If still not working, check if you have any firewall restriction on your local machine, on port 5432 and check if Postgres is set to recive data from external source.

Plus this example should be only used "at home", I do not suggest to use it in company network or any production environment.

Comment: is it possible to configure the docker in suck a way that i do not need to make postgres accept external connections??

Comment: @Hummingbird you could use a docker-compose option "network_mode: host" or docker host mode - https://docs.docker.com/network/host/ . Still suggested only for development environment.

Answer (score 0):

Accessing localhost inside a container is not your machine localhost. Instead find the ip of that docker program.

Find the ipaddress of the container

```
docker inspect containerName | grep IPAddress
```

Use this ip address instead of localhost